# /reputation for other users

Tags: support, reputation, users

I know about the superuser.com/reputation feature, but is there a native version of this feature I can use to do the same check on other users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

Not even moderators have the ability to see the reputation audit.

Comment: But they can try a faked version of what it might be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/does-the-reputation-graph-indicate-the-results-of-a-recalc

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no such tool. Maybe you could recreate the rep from the data dump?

Comment: Nice answer, was looking for a native feature to do this for me though! Thanks for thinking with me anyway!